# Value sliders are too fast

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, vertices, transforms

I've been trying the **spin tool** in new **Blender 2.81.**

I was trying to change the axis value so that I can get my desired result.

But the **value sliders for changing the position of the faces are quite fast** and I can't get the precise value I'm looking for without typing the value manually which can get very annoying.

Is there a way to slow the sliders down a bit or any other method to precisely change values other than typing?

I know that the <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> changes the value by 10 and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> makes it faster but I didn't find a key to make it slow.

I tried almost all the keys (except the alphabets), even crashed Blender and deleted my whole mesh accidentally but I couldn't find it.

**Anyone know how to slow the sliders** without crashing the whole thing?

Comment: Shift should slow down the operation

Comment: ... also, you can enter the angle numerically in the 'adjust last operation' panel

Comment: That was very useful. Thank you

Comment: Shift does slow down the operation but in some sliders it's opposite so i got confused. I thought it always makes them fast.